# jQuery - Finding xml children based on a variable argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, arguments

I am creating an application that converts an online form into various PDF forms to reduce admin burden. I am using an XML file so that users can enter a course code and the form will automatically populate some of its data to fill in the course information, however for the code below I am just using test files to figure it out first.

The user is to enter the course code in a text input and click a button to call Ajax to read the xml and create variables to populate the form. I have looked through dozens of tutorials and forums and can't seem to solve my problem - I need to filter the child nodes according to the course code entered, but I can only get it to work by entering the course code as text in the js file, when I attempt to use a variable argument it doesn't work and I have tried so many different ways.

**HTML...**

```
<html>
 <head><title>XML Reader</title></head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="argumentText">
 <input type="button" id="button" value="process">
 <input type="text" id="outputText">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**XML...**
Will have more coursecodes and child nodes eventually when I can get jQuery to work

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<course type="array">
 <coursecode>CWI416D01F
  <description>Signmaking L2</description>
 </coursecode>
 <coursecode>CWI490D01F
  <description>Business Admin L2</description>
 </coursecode>
 <coursecode>CWA061D01S
  <description>Dental Nurse L3</description>
 </coursecode>
</course>
```

**My jQuery...**
Note that the code below does actually work, but the outputVar that is created doesn't use the argumentVar at all...

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
 url: 'test.xml',
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'xml',
 success: function(data){

  //an argument is taken from the argumentText field
  var argumentVar = $("#argumentText").val();

  //Doing it this way works
  var outputVar = $(data).find('coursecode:contains(CWI416D01F)').children('description').text();

  //The outputVar is output as text in the outputText field, in this case "Signmaking L2"
  $('#outputText').val(outputVar);

 },
 error: function(){
 }  
}); //ajax is closed
}); //click function is closed
```

But I want the outputVar to take the argumentVar as the text argument in contains() rather than having to set updozens of cases in a switch, I have tried several methods, here are a couple of examples below...

```
var outputVar =
//Attempt 1
$(data).find('coursecode:contains(argumentVar)').children('description').text();

//Attempt 2
$(data).find('coursecode:contains('"+argumentVar+"')').children('description').text();

//Attempt 3 & 4 (I added an ID into each xml coursecode tag for this attempt)
$(data).find('coursecode[id="argumentVar"]').children('description').text();
$(data).find('coursecode[id=argumentVar]').children('description').text();
```

I've even tried a bunch of other different ways such as attempting to parse, if statements, filter return functions, you name it. Hopefully there is someone out there who can answer this, ideally with a really simple snippet of code.

Comment: Have you tried it like Attempt 2 but remove the single quotes surrounding the variable: //Attempt 2
$(data).find('coursecode:contains(' + argumentVar + ')').children('description').text();

Comment: aannndd... just like that it works! Haha. I can't believe I have spent hours on this problem and you solved it like that. Whenever I saw attempt 2 in other forums they did it the way I did, and I probably subconsciously thought the single quotes in contains would cancel out the quotes in find. 

Thanks for your prompt response buddy, you're the best!

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help. It's always nice to have a second pair of eyes to look at code, sometimes the littlest things can be the biggest problems.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered thanks to Ryan Wilson, here is answer in case anybody else confronting this problem...

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
 url: 'test.xml',
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'xml',
 success: function(data){

  //an argument is taken from the argumentText field
  var argumentVar = $("#argumentText").val();

  //This code finds a single xml node using the argumentVar variable
  var outputVar = $(data).find('coursecode:contains(' + argumentVar + ')').children('description').text();

  //The outputVar is output as text in the outputText field as according to whatever argument the user entered into argumentText
  $('#outputText').val(outputVar);

 },
 error: function(){
 }  
}); //ajax is closed
}); //click function is closed
```